# Creating Windows phone 8 Local Database Dynamically after retrieving metadata from server

Tags: database, windows-phone, local

how to create windows phone local db Dynamically i.e creating  DataContext and table schema at runtime after retrieving metadata from server. Dynamic database will create only once during first run of application

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains how you should create a local database. I used this and found it to be very helpful. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: i want to create local db database and table schema at runtime because i don't know about the attributes of table during coding and don't want to hard code datacontext class and table schema class